# How restore Backup DB2 v8?

Tags: db2, backup, restore

I have old backup of the db2 database which was made on v8
and need to restore

Latest version db2 say then

[db2inst1@db2server /]$ db2ckbkp /tmp/restore/20210320/122213.001

ERROR - Backup image from a release that is not supported.
Release ID -- 0xA00 (DB2 v8)
DB2CKBKP ERROR: Failed to verify media header .. Unknown Error. Refer to RC.
RC: 1 [x1] in db2ckbkp.C at line 644

I can't find install db2 v8
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is your target version of Db2-LUW (into which you want to restore the v8 database) ?  Was the backup taken on the __same__ operating system type , as your current Db2-server platform ?   Please __edit your question__ to add those facts.   Please don't use comments to add facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much is it worth? You need to be clear about that.

Db2-LUW typically lets you restore a database backup taken from up to **two** versions older than your current Db2-LUW level, as long as the **operating system** and architecture/endian-ness is the same (i.e. MS-Windows to MS-Windows, or  Linux x86/x64 to Linux x86/64).

At today's date the current Db2-LUW version is v11.5 which can restore databases no older than v10.5, which in turn accepts v9.7 databases, which in turn accepts v9.1 databases, which in turn accepts v8.x databases.  Hence the slow upgrade path is v8.x --> v9.1 --> v9.7 --> v10.5 --> v11.5  (your question does not mention your target Db2-LUW version).

That is if you use the `db2 restore` command to do the work. Hence you would need to have multiple different versions of Db2-LUW installed on their relevant supported operating-system (even temporarily) to be able to do the multi-stage restore by yourself.

If you have a running Db2 v8 environment, it would be a lot quicker and cheaper to just export the tables to flat files, zip them up, along with the full output of the `db2look` command on the source environment, along with the registry settings, any stored-procedures/routines source-code etc,  copy these to the target environment and finally create a database, adjust and run the DDL, and perform an import/load/ingest from the flat files. You might need to rebuild or reimplement old routines depending on how they are written.

If you do not have installable images for all the required intermediary Db2-LUW versions, plus their relevant operating-systems, then you would be stuck, as IBM does not make old images available by default.

If you do not have a running Db2 v8 environment, you might pay someone to do the work for you.  IBM would be able to help as long as you were willing to pay, hence the need to be clear about how much it is worth. If you have a regional Db2-LUW group, you might also find helpful local people who have one or more environments that might help (for a smaller fee).

IBM also has tools (separately available) that can extract data directly from backup images into a form that can be used with other databases. Again this would be a paid service, assuming your local IBM subsidiary can be engaged.